# Gridmap Node set_cell_item() rotation of the tile object

Tags: rotation, godot

I'm developing a procedural map using gridmap 3D in Godot,

```
set_cell_item(x: int, y: int, z: int, item: int, orientation: int = 0)
```

On the last property I can setup the orientation, of the object... but it looks like it ranges from -1 to 1...so, only 3 options?

Using then make my tile rotate in the Z axis, and I want it to rotate on the y axis. The docs point me to

`get_orthogonal_index()`

But I dindt understand how to use it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value goes from 0 to 24, where 0 is no rotation. The documentation of [`get_orthogonal_index`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_basis.html#class-basis-method-get-orthogonal-index)  says:

> This function considers a discretization of rotations into 24 points on unit sphere, lying along the vectors (x,y,z) with each component being either -1, 0, or 1, and returns the index of the point best representing the orientation of the object. It is mainly used by the GridMap editor. For further details, refer to the Godot source code.

What the 24 rotations are is not easy to visualize. However, suffice to say they are the [The Rotational Symmetries of the Cube](https://garsia.math.yorku.ca/%7Ezabrocki/math4160w03/cubesyms/). In other words, they are all the ways you can take a nondescript cube and rotate it, such that it looks the same after the rotation (it is rotated, but being a nondescript cube, it looks the same).

Now, the issue is in what order are these rotations?

Well, wonder no more, thanks to the magic of [*looking at Godot source code*](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.x/core/math/basis.cpp#L802), these are the rotations:

```
    //     --- x ---   --- y ---   --- z ---
    Basis( 1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1),  //  0
    Basis( 0, -1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1),  //  1
    Basis(-1,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  1),  //  2
    Basis( 0,  1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1),  //  3
    Basis( 1,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0),  //  4
    Basis( 0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0),  //  5
    Basis(-1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0),  //  6
    Basis( 0,  0, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0),  //  7
    Basis( 1,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0, -1),  //  8
    Basis( 0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1),  //  9
    Basis(-1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0, -1),  // 10
    Basis( 0, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1),  // 11
    Basis( 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0, -1,  0),  // 12
    Basis( 0,  0, -1,  1,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0),  // 13
    Basis(-1,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0),  // 14
    Basis( 0,  0,  1, -1,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0),  // 15
    Basis( 0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0, -1,  0,  0),  // 16
    Basis( 0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  1, -1,  0,  0),  // 17
    Basis( 0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0),  // 18
    Basis( 0,  1,  0,  0,  0, -1, -1,  0,  0),  // 19
    Basis( 0,  0,  1,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0,  0),  // 20
    Basis( 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0),  // 21
    Basis( 0,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0),  // 22
    Basis( 0, -1,  0,  0,  0, -1,  1,  0,  0)   // 23
```

These are `Basis`. They describe the orientation by specifying the direction of the axis.

The three first numbers are the x axis, followed by three numbers for the y axis, and three more for the z axis.

The first one, is no rotation at all:

```
Basis( 1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1),  //  0
```

Notice that the x axis is `1,0,0`, which means it is oriented towards the x. The y axis is `0,1,0`… you guested oriented towards the y, and `0,0,1` for the z being just the z. So no rotation, as expected.

As you can see the first four indexes gives you rotation that keep the z axis untouched. Thus, you see rotation around the z axis.

Since you want rotation around the y axis, let us pick the ones that keep the y axis untouched:

```
    Basis( 1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1),  //  0
    Basis(-1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0, -1),  // 10
    Basis( 0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0, -1,  0,  0),  // 16
    Basis( 0,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0),  // 22
```

As per the order… 0 is no rotation. 10 is half turn, since the other axis are flipped. Thus, either 0, 22, 10, 16 or 0, 16, 10, 22, depending if you want a positive or negative rotation.

Comment: I don't thing you could give a more perfect answer then this one... I really appreciate your answer. It completely solve my question

Comment: Why don't you open a PR for the official docs? I arrived here trying to undestand what I get back from GridMap.get_cell_item_orientation() and I can't get how they could leave it at "oh it returns an int"...